# 403 on ajax request to own domain

Tags: ajax, django, facebook, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to use an ajax request to call a function in a different view, but I'm getting a 403 error.

excerpt from my template:

```
    FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests', title: 'Invite your friends to answer questions!', message:'Invite your friends!'},
    function(response) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "/canvas/request/",
            type: "post",
            data: {qid: {{ qid }} , request_ids: response.request_ids}
        })
    });
```

excerpt from my view:

```
def save_request(request):
    print("in save request")
    for id in request.request_ids:
        share = ShareRequest
        share.question = request.qid
        share.share_id = id
        share.save()
```

excerpt from my urls:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(...
    (r'^request/', save_request),
```

returns [06/Sep/2011 13:35:56] "POST /canvas/request/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2332

I'm really confused.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you need to add the CSRF token to your request?  Some details are at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/.

Comment: I thought of that, but it isn't a cross-site request. I think I'll try it anyway, though

Comment: @Colleen you seem to have a completely mistaken understanding of what CSRF protection is all about. Please read Dylan's link.

Comment: I did misunderstand... I tried including the js code that the documentation says "Adding this to a javascript file that is included on your site will ensure that AJAX POST requests that are made via jQuery will not be caught by the CSRF protection.", but then my page was not loaded...

Answer (score 4):

**BAD but QUICK solution for keep yourself not in the stealth mode:**

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
```

use this `@csrf_exempt` decorator at your views to ignore the csrf issue.

But This is a bad habbit. So make sure your sites `csrf` protected. And follow the django documentation.

Comment: Thanks, I did this for now. Need to investigate why Django's js code breaks my page...